# I compiled herbstluftwm via its git repo but I can't see it in lightdm?

Tags: 18.04, compiling, lightdm, window-manager

Everything went successful.

```
git clone https://github.com/herbstluftwm/herbstluftwm
cd herbstluftwm
mkdir -p build; cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with person from wm's IRC helps.
Install wm from apt, do thing that I said above. after those thing, you must do move herbstluftwm and herbstclient to /usr/bin. Restart when you done those things.

Comment: And `/usr/local/share/xsessions/herbstluftwm.desktop` must be linked/copied to `/usr/share/xessions/`